# React with typescript, button function doesn't work

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm slowly starting to learn TS and implement it to current project however I stuck and don't really understand what is wrong. Basically I have button which has dataset "mode". After clicking on button I launch confirm bar (confirm bar is not TSX yet)

```
<Button
      height={50}
      data-mode="MEMORY"
      onClick={(e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>) =>
        ConfirmBar('You sure?', supportCommands, e)
      }
    >
      Format
    </Button>


const ConfirmBar = (message, action, parameter) =>
  confirmAlert({
    customUI: ({ onClose }) => {
      return (
        <ConfirmContainer>
          <Header main>{message}</Header>
          <ConfirmationButton
            confirm
            onClick={() => {
              action(parameter);
              onClose();
            }}
          >
            Yes
          </ConfirmationButton>
          <ConfirmationButton onClick={onClose}>No</ConfirmationButton>
        </ConfirmContainer>
      );
    },
  });
```

In case of yes I wish to launch function to proceed request, it worked correctly before typescript but now it throws error. I wish to get access to dataset attribute and would be glad if you guys help me and explain me why it doesn't want to work now after added typescript

```
 const supportCommands = (el: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>) => {
// Tried already to use el.persist(), with target and currentTarget; here is example with attempting to assign value to variable but also doesn't work.
    const target = el.currentTarget as HTMLButtonElement;
    let elVal = target.getAttribute('data-mode');
    console.log(elVal, 'ELL');
  };
```

And that's the error I occur:

> Warning: This synthetic event is reused for performance reasons. If
> you're seeing this, you're accessing the method `currentTarget` on a
> released/nullified synthetic event. This is a no-op function. If you
> must keep the original synthetic event around, use event.persist().
> See fb.me/react-event-pooling for more information.

I understand that React has own system of SynthesisEvents but I thought they cause problems during asynchronous requests like with timers etc, in this situation I see no reason why it makes problem

EDIT: I made it work by adding to button e.currentTarget, and then in function just did el.dataset, now just trying to figure out what kind of type is that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This `waring` is because you are reusing `Event` object.

You passed it here `ConfirmBar('You sure?', supportCommands, e)`

And you reused it here `action(parameter);`

I don't know what do you need from `paramenter` but I guess it could be like this:

```js
    onClick={(e) => {
        action(e);
        onClose();
    }}
```

I have never needed to use `event` of `onClick`. The only idea I can imagine is for `preventDefault` or `stopPropagation`

Comment: Hello Thanks for answer. Reason why I pass event of onClick was because I wished to have access to dataset properties of the button. There is many buttons and some of them have more datasets than just data-mode, So I wanted to pass event, then confirm it in confirm bar and then pass it to the function where I would get access to all dataset properties I need. If I use it as you showed above then I won't get event of the button I clicked first, but the button from confirmation bar which doesn't have any datasets

Comment: then instead of passing the `Event`, you can extract the data and pass only the things you need: `const { your_data } = e; ConfirmBar('You sure?', supportCommands, your_data)`

Comment: oh I didn't think of that, this way I can give it a proper type and pass to function only necessary data instead of whole event.  Thanks mate, write it as an answer and I will mark it:)